# How to control the size of the figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Without using the include graphic, placing directly within the text a design using TikZ, you can control the size of the figure?

Comment: You can use `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.7]` for example.

Comment: Or you can resize a box which includes the picture. `\resizebox{width}{height}{contents}`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `scale`-Option, such as

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

or the short syntax, which is convenient for small images within text:

```
\tikz[scale=0.5]
```

To apply that scaling also to contained shapes, you may want to add the corresponding option:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5, transform shape]
...
\end{tikzpicture}
```

As cfr already commented, you can use the LaTeX scaling tools, such as `\scalebox` and `\resizebox`. Both have the advantage of scaling all easily, but note that scaling fonts is not so good compared to directly using the font in a certain size. With `\resizebox` you can directly specify the desired size instead of a scaling factor.

```
\resizebox{width}{height}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    ...
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
```